# Conditional Formatting for Blank Cell Does not Give Expected Result

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format a cell, the goal is to have a Green Fill if the adjacent cell (on left) is blank and Red Fill if not blank. Below is the Code applied to Column D

```
="ISBlank(($C$2)"
```

and a snapshot below target cell
[image: Snapshot of Ecel Implimentation]

I am not getting the Desired result, the cells in column D remain white (excel default format of cells)

Please see the Data I am using below
[image: DATA]

Comment: Also (separate from my below answer), why is there an extra parens in the above? Are the quotes also going into the formula? Try =isblank($c$2)

Comment: Does not work, still same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the $ before the 2 in =ISBLANK($C$2) otherwisethe conditional formatting will only refer to C2. I think you'll want:

```
=ISBLANK($C2)
```

Also if the contents in column C is ="" , ISBLANK will return FALSE, assuming you don't want that behavior, you could try:

```
=LEN($C2)>0
```

Which checks how long the text is in C2.

Example:

[image]

Comment: sorry but your answer is not working. Still stays Excel Default format

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the data you are using?

Comment: As andrew said there shouldn't be any "" in your formula. Also you will want to change the "Applies To" to be all of relevant data in column D

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally I've also had trouble getting is blank() to work properly. What I would try is:

```
$d$2 = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

1] Do way with the double inverted commas
2] The Applies to range must be more than a single cell if you want the CF to apply across a range of more than one cell
3] You don't need two rules

Select ColumnD and 'standard' fill red. (Remove fill from D1 if preferred). Select ColumnD (this sets the Applies to range) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=ISBLANK(C1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green Fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

You do not need to lock the column reference because you are only applying the CF to a single column. You must not lock the row reference if to apply to multiple rows on a row by row basis.

With the above if a cell is red and has an *apparently* empty cell on its left then that cell is not actually empty.